# What type of cord is this and where can I get it

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug, range-hood

It says the following on the cord and I believe it goes to the range.

(ul) 3 cdrs 6 al. type se style cable style u type xhhw 300V 10 ground

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's not a cord ... it is a cable ... the word it is printed right on it

Comment: You are forbidden from extending it.

Answer (score 5):

Ovens need 4 wires: 2 hot wires, neutral and ground.  The neutral is needed for 120V loads inside the oven, notably the oven light. The ground is needed for safety, *we tried*.

In 1966 when grounding was required everywhere else, a 3-wire connection *with no ground* was allowed for awhile longer and finally banned in 1996 because of the tragedies. That is what you are looking at right there.

Any oven, range or cooktop which requires neutral **will require a 4-wire connection** and this cable is unusable for that. You are forbidden from extending it.

Your only option is to scrap it (or abandon it in place) and run a new cable of one of these types.

- 6 AWG aluminum SE-R 4-wire (assuming 75°C terminal) - the direct replacement for this type
- 8 AWG copper SE-R 4-wire also assuming 75°C thermal
- 6 AWG copper NM-B (Romex) or UF-B

You may want to take a Dramamine before checking the prices of copper. Some people are wiggy about aluminum, but it's fine if you follow the 1 rule:  use it on terminals *properly rated* for aluminum*. There's also the "torque all terminals to spec" rule, but that applies equally to copper.  It's just that when copper burns up because the rule was not followed, nobody blames the copper lol.

---

If you find yourself with cooktop and oven *separates* in the future, cooktops typically do not require neutral, and they can use a 3-wire *hot-hot-ground* connection.  In that case, the bare **neutral** in this SE-U cable can be permanently re-tasked to be a ground wire. (that is permitted by NEC).

Comment: So you’re saying if I cut that open it will just be two hot and a ground?

Comment: @Avi no, you'll find two hots **and a netural**. With SEU cable, the mesh is neutral. However you can reassign it to ground if going to a NEMA 6-50 connector or if hardwiring to a cooktop.

Comment: It is currently going to my range but I need to extend it a few feet to move it

Comment: @Avi you'll need to scrap this and re-run the whole thing with one of the cables I mentioned.  Sorry. But #6 AL SER is cheap.  If it's cord-and-plug, change the socket and cord to NEMA 14-50.  This is also safer for your family.